# Does anyone know of a good StackOverflow/Bulletin type program for Java/Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I am making a website for my school that is going to house a lot of data about:

- Dining Hall Foods
- Sports News & Rosters
- University Events

I also wanted to see if I could try and add a Q&A(or forum) type of site for students.

I already know there are numerous types out there(php based), I was just wondering if there were any Java/Tomcat based ones since I am already using that for the other functionality. I'd prefer if I could use Tomcat so I don't have to manage a whole other web server.

Comment: Will that help? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Comment: Ahh, did not even know about that. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

This has already being discussed on Meta. Please, refer to:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones